# Android Parse - Cannot resolve symbol 'FindCallBack'

Tags: android, parse-platform

I'm trying to query the Parse database and get the error: Cannot resolve symbol 'FindCallBack'.
I've tried using 'query.find' but I was informed that 'findInBackground' is more effective.
The main goal is to query the info and iterate the list for future use.
The query itself works when I use 'query.find', but the iteration fails, as if I'm trying to access an invalid field.

**'FindCallBack' version**

```
import com.parse.Parse;
import com.parse.ParseObject;
import com.parse.ParseQuery;
import com.parse.SaveCallback;
import com.parse.ParseException;
import com.parse.FindCallback;


import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.List;

public class ListNodeActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    private  Task t = new Task();
    private Spinner spin;
    private Spinner empolyeeSpinner;
    private int task_id=1;
    private String time_Date_str = null;
    private Locations returned_selc_loc;
    private EditText loc;

    private ParseObject parse_task=null;
    private DBManager dbm;

    private static final int ACTIVITY_SELECT_LOCATION = 0;
    private ParseObject team_members = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_node);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        //check is username & password exist
        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("OTSUser");
        query.whereContains("TeamName", Globals.team_name);
        query.whereEqualTo("IsManager",0);

        query.findInBackground(new FindCallBack<ParseObject>() {
            public void done(List<ParseObject> usrs;ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < usrs.size(); i++) {
                        Log.w("debug", usrs.get(i).getString("Userame"));
                    }
                } else {//handle the error
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**'query.find' version**

```
//check is username & password exist
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("OTSUser");
query.whereContains("TeamName", Globals.team_name);
query.whereEqualTo("IsManager",0);
List<ParseObject> usrs=null;

try {
    usrs = query.find();
    Log.w("debug","size of usrs "+usrs.size());
    for (int i = 0; i < usrs.size(); i++)
    {
     //   empolyeeSpinnerAdapter.add(usrs.get(i).getString("Userame"));
        Log.w("debug",usrs.get(i).getString("Userame"));
    }
} catch (ParseException e) {}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two typos causing this to fail. First the class name is `FindCallback` with a lowercase 'b'.

You are also using a ';' instead of a ',' to separate the parameters in the `done(...)` method. Change the method to the following and you should be on your way.

```
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
    public void done(List<ParseObject> usrs, ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < usrs.size(); i++) {
                Log.w("debug", usrs.get(i).getString("Userame"));
            }
        } else {//handle the error
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Can't believe I missed that. Thank you.